# Magento 2.3: How to override page content

Tags: magento2, overrides, page

[image]

How to override the content editing page to customize it. do you have any ideas?

Comment: Please explain in details.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I want to remove the content editing page and replace it with another one in my custom module.

Answer (score 0):

Basically we are not able to override page content. But what we can do is,

We have to create Separated Multiple Blocks, So that we can call in any Page.

Comment: Sorry, but this is possible.

Comment: could you please tell me, how?

Comment: I have a module that can do it but it is quite complicated, it does not help me clear.

Comment: Yes, Exactly, we need some customization, that will help in this activity.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?